# Persephone Super Moves in 2v2

Tags: yomi

Two questions about how Persephone's super move *Mistress's Command* function in 2v2 mode.

1) If Persephone hits with *Mistress's Command* and then tags out to an ally (2v2 mode) before the next turn (either through powering up at the end of that turn, or using a Super Cancel Tag out of *Mistress's Command*), **does the effect of *Mistress's Command* come into play on the next turn with her ally now active?** If so, which player controls the enemy character, her or her ally? (Naturally, teammates can collaborate with each other, but one of them has to have the authority to make the plays).

2) **Does the Super Cancel Tag rule of "half damage rounded down" have a clause of "to a minimum of 1"** that was overlooked in the manual and was errata'd in? It occurs to me that Persephone's *Mistress's Command* is the only move in the game presently that would be affected, and the difference between it doing 1 damage or 0 damage is probably non-trivial based in various technical cases.

EDIT: Onimaru's *Clockwork Soldiers* would also be affected by #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game creator David Sirlin [answered both of these questions](http://www.fantasystrike.com/forums/index.php?threads/few-persephone-2v2-clarifications.9257/#post-306018) recently on the forums.

1) **Persephone controls the opponent on the following turn from the bench.**

> Abilities work from the bench. It says you control their turn.

2)  Mistress's Command (and Onimaru's Clockwork Soldiers) intentionally do 1 damage and there is no minimum associated with the rounding of the Super Cancel Tag specifically so that **its effect will not trigger** in such a scenario.

> "Rounded down" is specifically so that MC and CS do 0. Very much on
>   purpose.